# How do I resolve "Failed to find provider info for com.new.newapp.activity.locations"?

Tags: android

I keep getting this error now in my app and not sure how to resolve.  (I had a previous issue with the cursor, but think I have resolved that now)  But now am getting this:

```
Failed to find provider info for com.new.newapp.activity.locations
```

So in my `LocationsContentProvider` class:

```
package com.new.newapp.activity;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;

public class LocationsContentProvider extends ContentProvider{

public static final String PROVIDER_NAME  = "com.new.newapp.activity.locations";
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" +  PROVIDER_NAME + "/locations" );
private static final int LOCATIONS = 1;
private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher ;

static {
    uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "locations", LOCATIONS);
}

LocationsDB mLocationsDB;
```

And in my Manifest:

```
 </application>

 <provider
    android:authorities="com.new.newapp.activity.locations"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:multiprocess="true"
    android:name="locations"
    android:exported="true" ></provider>

 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
    <data android:mimeType="video/*"/>
    <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
 </intent-filter>

 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

 </manifest>
```

I have tried several suggestions but none has helped me.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

**EDIT**

This is what I seem to get now-

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.new.newapp.activity/locations
        at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1213)
        at com.new.newapp.activity.FragmentGoogleMap$LocationInsertTask.doInBackground(FragmentGoogleMap.java:343)
        at com.new.newapp.activity.FragmentGoogleMap$LocationInsertTask.doInBackground(FragmentGoogleMap.java:340)
```

And the lines associated are-

```
 @Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
}
340 --> class LocationInsertTask extends AsyncTask<ContentValues, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(ContentValues... contentValues) {
343 --> getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(LocationsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, contentValues[0]);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step #1: Move your `<provider>` element inside the `<application>` element.

Step #2: Get rid of the random `<intent-filter>` element that is not associated with anything.

The documentation for the manifest elements will tell you where they belong. For example, [the documentation for `<provider>` tells you that it is contained within `<application>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but am still getting the error with this: (I have updated my question)